# Из string в System.Uri

Tags: c#, webbrowser

Начал работать с интернетом в c# и тут же возник такой вопрос. Как сделать так, чтобы webBrowser считывал textbox.Text и записывал в свойство url?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Примерно так:

```
try {
    webbrowser.Navigate(new Uri(textbox.text));
}
catch (System.UriFormatException e) {
}
```

Где в `textbox.text` лежит что-нибудь вроде `http://hashcode.ru/`.

Comment: Всё спасибо, уже сам нашёл.

Answer (score 1):

```
var uri = new Uri(textbox1.Text);
```

[Uri на MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/txt7706a.aspx).